# Mock document.getElemetById('.form').getContext('2d') using sinon

Tags: html, angularjs, unit-testing, sinon, angular-mock

I'm using karma, mocha, chai, sinon and Angular mocks for my unit testing. In my **$scope.loadChart**, 
I'm drawing a chart in my canvas tag. I'm using http://www.chartjs.org/ to draw the charts.

Chartjs requires this piece of code, **document.getElemetById('#canvas').getContext('2d')**. How do I stub this in Sinon? My test is stuck with this line.

Answer (score 8):

You could stub `document.getElementById` and have it return a canvas object that is stubbed and programmed to return a context object of your choosing...

```
//Create your fake canvas and context objects
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var fakeContext = {}; //Replace this with whatever you want your fake context to be

//Have `canvas.getContext('2d')` return your fake context
sinon.stub(canvas, 'getContext');
canvas.getContext.withArgs('2d').returns(fakeContext);

//Have `document.getElementById('canvas')` return your canvas
sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById');
document.getElementById.withArgs('canvas').returns(canvas);
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am getting an error message:
`TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property`

Comment: Which line of the example causes that error for you?

Comment: `document.getElementById.withArgs('canvas')`, I am trying to mock `createElement()` though

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap that DOM access in a method. Then you can mock that method.

```
var DomAccess = function() {} 
DomAccess.prototype.get2dCanvas = function() {
    return document.getElementById('#canvas').getContext('2d');
}

var domAccess = new DomAccess();
var context = domAccess.get2dContext();
```

You can now mock this class the usual way with sinon.